# What does the "typecheck" npm script in Vue projects using Vite and TS do?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

I created a new Vue project using TypeScript and Vite via

`npm init vue@latest`

Inside the package.json file there is a *typecheck* script

```
"typecheck": "vue-tsc --noEmit -p tsconfig.vitest.json --composite false",
```

but I don't know its purpose. Should I use this script to ensure that my code is fine? ( E.g. for QA workflows )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Vite` bundler does not perform type checking; so by default - if there are any errors in your `TypeScript` code - `Vite` will not complain and transpile it as normal (this is part of the reason why it is so fast).

The `"typecheck"` script will do as it's name suggests, check for any `TypeScript` errors in your `.ts` and `.vue` files via the `vue-tsc --noEmit` command. It is important to understand that this script will not watch for changes and only run once
per execution. Nevertheless, it is a vital script and should be run as much as possible, especially as part of your CI/CD build process.

It is also worth noting that you can change the start of the script to `"tsc --noEmit` to typecheck `.ts` files exclusively.

Ref to the [documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#typescript).